# Recovering an account without knowing the email address

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

Over a year ago, I first started out on Stack Overflow thinking I was just going to use it once, and then leave, so I created an account using one of those temporary email addresses. Yesterday, my hard drive started dying, forcing a reformat, etc, and long story short, I don't remember the email address I used for signing up, even though I know the password. Is there any way for me to find the email address?

I'm not overly miffed about the whole situation, but I was in the middle of a question, and now, even with a new account, I can't make a comment to say that I won't be able to continue with my question for the time being, because I need a minimum of 50 reputation.

If it is possible to find the email address, would it also be possible to change the email address to the account I'm currently using?

Comment: Cheers. I'll get right on that.

Comment: That might be a better dup...

Comment: It's alright, I found the right place to go to, so I've filled out the form over on Stack Overflow.

And now to play the waiting game! That, and frantically recover whatever files I can from my hard drive.